# Pumping Lemma, Condition 1

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

> Let B be the language {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup> | n >= 0} i.e. 0 and 1 has to have the same length
>
> Let s in B be the string 0<sup>p</sup>1<sup>p</sup>
>
> Assume B is regular so s must be divisible to s = xyz where xy<sup>i</sup>z i>=0 is still in B (Condition 1 of three conditions of pumping lemma).
>
> Consider the case xy<sup>i</sup>z where i = 2 so xyyz:
> Pump y with all 0s
> xyyz has more 0s and 1s so it cannot be in B. Therefore, B is not regular.

I am having a hard time understanding that if y is all 0s in xyyz, then # of 0s > # of 1s

Why can't |xyy| = |z| which then it would have the same # of 0s and 1s?

Comment: This probably goes in Theoretical CS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Pump y with all 0s' isn't terribly clear, but an example of how this works out is as follows:

```
Pick some value for y: let's say y = '0'.
Pick some value for i: i = 1
Then s = xyz.  We will assume this holds true for the moment.
```

Now, since we assume B is regular, we know that - for any value of i - the string formed by xy<sup>i</sup>z should also be in B! Let's try xyyz, like you suggest.

...Uh-oh.  You see the problem? We have to hold y constant, but doing so means we just made a string that has one more 0 than s, but doesn't have an extra 1 to go with it! We just showed that y can't be 0.  Well, darn.

Now consider: is there any value of y for which this won't hold true? Adding 0s to y will only make the issue worse!

This is a very informal walkthrough of the proof, but hopefully it helps understand why it works.

Comment: So, with your example, lets say x = '0' and y = '0' then in xyyz, xyy = '000' why cant z be '111' (which means they are the same)? The variable x, y, z does not have to have a length of 1.

Comment: Correct.  BUT you've only shown that for one value of i.  Your selection of x, y and z only 'fit' the language if xy^iz is in the language for all values of i >= 0.